# change the button color according to what we want with phaser 3

Tags: javascript, typescript, phaser-framework

I'm just learning to make a button, to change the color of the button when we hover over one clickable image. for example when we point the cursor to one of the colored images, (red, blue, yellow), then when we click the color image that we like for example click the yellow color,
then the button changes, to yellow, is there an example for me in the phaser that points to it, using phaser 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the images and the button, and use `setTint()` to change the button color. (Or `setTintFill()`.)

```
var image1 = this.add.image(....);
var image2 = this.add.image(....);
...
image1.setInteractive().on('pointerdown', function() {myButton.setTint(0xff0000)});
image2.setInteractive().on('pointerdown', function() {myButton.setTint(0x0000ff)});
```

The funny thing in your example is that you want to use images as buttons, and a button as an image...

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with vanilla JS, take a look on the example: https://codepen.io/lessadiogo/pen/yLyvxQQ

HTML:

```
<div class="img" data-color="yellow" onclick="changeBtnColor('yellow')"></div>
<div class="img" data-color="green" onclick="changeBtnColor('green')"></div>
<button>I got changed!</button>
```

CSS:

```
.img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.img[data-color=yellow] {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.img[data-color=green] {
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

button {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

span {
  padding-top: 40px;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px
}
```

Javascript:

```
function changeBtnColor(color) {
  document.querySelector('button').style.background = color
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for checking, but it doesn't seem to work in phaser 3, but I'll try it out

Comment: I got your point.. phaser game framework? Can you share your code? It's hard to reproduce something working if we don't know what you're doing exactly, eg: how are you creating these images and buttons, etc.

Comment: for example we choose the cursor with a yellow ball and then we click on the ball, then one of the buttons in the link changes to yellow,

foto
https://github.com/ariffadhillah/foto/blob/master/Untitled.png

kode
https://github.com/ariffadhillah/Game-Gewgly/blob/master/src/games/gewgly/scenes/stationaryScene.ts#L102

Answer (score 0):

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59648441/988246) *works*, but it has a couple of caveats. `setTint` is a multiplicative function: it takes the pixel colour of the game object (images, in this case) and *multiplies* it by the given colour. If your base images are pure white, then it will work great and you've got no problem. However, if your images (or text, or whatever you use) are a different colour, then it won't work as expected.

Take the following example, where I've used a Text object:

[image: Text in Phaser 3 with 'Game Menu' written out 3 times; the first in pale yellow, the second in bright pink, the third in more of a kind of hot fuscia]

The first line of text has a base colour of `#F2E675`. The second line of text has a base colour of `#FFFFFF` (pure white), but with `.setTint(0xFF00FF)` applied. And it works great!

However, the *third* line has the same pale yellow base colour as the first (`#F2E675`). When I apply `.setTint(0xFF00FF)`, it actually comes out as `#F20075` - more like a kind of hot fuscia. And this is because the *base colour* is different, and since tint *multiplies*, the outcome looks different. And if your text (or image) is black, then `setTint()` will do nothing, because - just like maths - multiplying a number by `#000000` will still give you `#000000`.

If you're using Text as I am here, you can instead use [`setColor()`](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Text.html#setColor__anchor). The following image is identical to the one above - 3 lines of text in pale yellow, pure white and pale yellow again, but this time using `.setColor('#FF00FF')` on both the white & yellow text. As you can see, in both instances, the text is actually showing as `#FF00FF`.

[image: The same image as above, but this time both white & yellow texts are showing the correct shade of hot pink when setColor() is applied]

**Note that** `setColor()` is a function of Text. If you want to swap colours for an image, either use `setTint` as above, or (if that doesn't give you the results you want) generate a separate rollover image and use that.